# file not found in apache server : PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

I have below directory structure in `PHP` application.

[image]

Last 2 files I can access it. but, when I try to open first 2 files, it says file not found. I checked it all files are there. And same permissions given to all files.

I don't know what's wrong in here.

This is `conf` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap manglelow int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${manglelow:$1}
```

Comment: is `PNG` case the case? Are you trying to access using `png`?

Comment: No. It's in uppercase when I am trying to access it

Comment: How does PHP relate to your question? Are you opening the files as URLs from PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`manglelow` converts the `URL` to lower case this means that your files need to be lower case to work.

/assets/img/logos/logo-lg.pnG

will pull up the file

/assets/img/logos/logo-lg.png

just rename your files to be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue here that the Reweite only matches for files that start with letter but the other files start with numbers? try [0-9A-Z] instead of [A-Z]